# Configure Zend Framework in MAMP

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, mamp

I'm new to Zend Framework. I'm trying to learn it for future projects.
I've got MAMP running on my machine and I've deployed ZendFramework-1.11.11 in my MAMP/htdocs
 folder.

However when I want to view a demo, I get the following message:
**HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.**

The Install file asks me to add the library directory to my PHP include_path, but I cannot find any php.ini or other file where I could set that (I can view hidden files)

How can I get this to work?

NB: I am able to run the zendtests/jukebox demo app from the same location without any problems.
NB2: Anyone knows where I can find a basic Zend shell for a basic website+admin that I could experiment with?

Comment: First check the [Apache error log](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/faq/where-can-i-find-the-logs/where-can-i-find-the-apache-error-log)

Answer (score 2):

PHP.ini is located at:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.2
```

or

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3
```

It depends on the used PHP Version by MAMP.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like most of the demos work now (not all of them though)

Comment: @nickmortensen, nice catch, now [all links from that site](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fthinkclay.com) go to Linkedin... ArneRie, [here's the archived page](https://web.archive.org/web/20140210001922/http://thinkclay.com/technology/installing-zend-framework-on-mamp) if you want to incorporate the code here.